# Webpack environment variable are unknown argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to create a webpack setup but can't manage to make it work with the environment variables.
I have read the doc more than 10 times but can't find the solution.

My package json has this script:

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --env.MODE=production "
```

But when I'm running it, node is telling me:

```
webpack: Unknown argument: --env.MODE=production
Usage: webpack --config <path to webpack configuration file> e.g. ./webpack.config.js
Description: Provide path to a webpack configuration file
Documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/
```

EDIT: I finally found the solution.
The webpack-ci installed version was "webpack-cli": "^4.0.0-beta.2".
I downgraded it and it's now working fine.

Comment: Try just --env.production after webpack.config.js. Although without webpack version and webpack.config.js file in the question, it's just a guess.

Comment: Didn't work, giving me the same error, Unknow argument --env.production

Comment: Wel, provide the webpack.config.js then :)

Comment: The WebPack config isn't working properly since I'm trying to make these variables working but I didn't forgot to export a function
module.exports = env => {...}

Comment: Try to update your webpack globally, maybe you are using the newer version in the config.

Comment: I'm using the same version because It's the first time I install webpack. Everything should be up to date

Comment: @ElliotYoYo Downgrading is not a solution :) It is the wrong way for cool developers like  me. My answer is correct, accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Just use with spacing..

```
"build": "webpack --mode=production --config webpack.config.js --env MODE=production"
```

Now you can parse it like:

```
module.exports = ({ MODE }, { mode }) => {...}
```

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it you can view the file [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/package.json)

```
  "prod": "webpack -p --mode=production --config webpack.prod.js",
  "start": "webpack --mode=development --config webpack.dev.js",
```